# Difference between AEGenerator and Generator in the SEGAN model for speech enhancement

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, speech, generative-adversarial-network

Recently, I read a paper *[SEGAN: Speech Enhancement Generative Adversarial Network](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.09452)*. However, I didn't understand the definition of a generator in the code, which can be found [here](https://github.com/santi-pdp/segan/blob/master/model.py). Why are there two kinds of generators, `AEGenerator` and `Generator`?. Is there any difference between them? Besides, there are also two models: `SEGAN` model and `SEAE` model. What is the relationship between these two models and these two generators?

```
class SEGAN(Model):
    """ Speech Enhancement Generative Adversarial Network """
    def __init__(self, sess, args, devices, infer=False, name='SEGAN'):

class SEAE(Model):
    """ Speech Enhancement Auto Encoder """
    def __init__(self, sess, args, devices, infer=False):
```

In the paper, the G network lookes like a encoder-decoder architecture, which performs the enhancement. With which generator does our speech enhancement work? Why define two generator models?

[image: Encoder-decoder architecture for speech enhancement (G network)]

Comment: Improved wording, inlined picture, added link to paper and code, adjusted title and tags.